With keras 3.2.1 and tensorflow 2.16.1 the output of calling "model.metrics" is ['loss', 'compile_metrics'] after loading a model with keras tuner
A search for the best parameters for a model (namely U-Net) for multiclassification was performed and when compiling the model within the so-called 'model_builder' function two metrics were included: categorical accuracy and f1. However when reloading the models after the search using keras tuner the output of using model.metrics or model.evaluate is: ['loss', 'compile_metrics']. It shows neither accuracy nor f1.
Does anyone know what it could be?
---Piece of code---
Model builder:
METRICS = [
keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
f1_weighted
]
 # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
# Choose an optimal value from 0.01, 0.001, or 0.0001
hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalFocalCrossentropy()

model.compile(loss=loss,
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=METRICS,
              jit_compile=False)
  
return model

Output:
model = model_builder(best_hps[0])
model.metrics_names

['loss', 'compile_metrics']


Hi@saroalre,you are facing an issue when the matrices that you defined during model compilation are not
Showing correctly.check it is correctly implemented and accessible during model compilation. After reloading the model from the tuner recompile the model and check metric working correctly during evaluation.Try this if you still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
